# DirectX 9 Preserve State Across Reset Calls

Tags: c++, directx-9

I need to keep my IDirect3DStateBlock9 across a IDirect3DDevice9::Reset call. How can I do this? I know it needs to be released, but is there a way to store the data inside the state so that I can apply it to the device?

Answer (score 0):

Direct3D 9 state blocks are opaque. You can't serialize them, and if the device was created with `D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE`, you can't use any `Get` methods to try to recover the individual state settings.

Once the `Reset` has occurred, you basically have to set all the state you need again.